# Side Menu and the page does not responds after setting root page again Ionic 2 Beta 11

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic-view

Hi i am using Ionic 2 Beta 11.
I am on login page after login i am setting a page as a root page after login the page shows and menu icon shows also but when i click on page button and menu icon on the screen of the page then page does not responds and also the menu does not work to.
i tried these solutions but none of these work

```
this.navCtrl.setRoot(AppointmentsPage);
```

and

```
 this.app.getRootNav().setRoot(AppointmentsPage)
```

Here is my code.

```
onLogin(form) {
      this.submitted = true;
if (form.valid) {
    this.networkservice.showLoading();
    var data = this.userData.login(this.login.email,this.login.password);
    console.log(data);
    data.subscribe(res => {
          if(res.length == 0  ) {
            this.login.isVaild = false;
            this.networkservice.hideLoading();  
          }else{
            this.userData.setDoctor(res[0]);
            this.hideLoading();
            this.navCtrl.setRoot(AppointmentsPage);


          }

        });

  }else{
  }

}
```

Kindly help me on this issue

Answer (score 0):

If anyone face this problem, I think I have found the main issue in this cenary. The problem occurs when you are pushing from a "modal" or "popover" and so it happens the navigation problem. To do this the right way, execute the **push** or **setRoot** 'from the page that calls popover or modal instead'. This can be done easily with the 'onDidDismiss' function:

```
//Page which calls popover:
popover.create();

//Page popover: Dismiss existing popover (you may also pass a parameter)
popover.dismiss(myParameter);

//Page which calls popover: Veriry if popover was removed
popover.onDidDismiss(data => {
    if(data == "something")
    {
        //Navigate to new page
        this.nav.push(newPage)
    }
});
```

Hope it helps someone!